# How to send a stream of websocket messages using the send_all method of tokio-tungstenite

Tags: rust

I am using the excellent rust websocket library tokio-tungstenite, which is just the tokio version of tungstenite.

I can easily connect to a websocket stream using the connect_async method and in the websocket stream I get back I split it as follows:

```
connect_async(url).and_then(move |(ws_stream, _)| {

        let (sink, stream) = ws_stream.split();
```

I can easily send a single message down the sink using the send message like this:

```
sink.send(tungstenite::Message::Text("my message".to_string()))
.map_err(|e| ())
.wait();
```

That is just a contrived example. My problem is I want to send a stream of messages down the sink which I've learned is best accomplished using the send_all method. My attempt is:

```
let my_messsages : Vec<tungstenite::Message> = vec![
tungstenite::Message::Text("message_1".to_string()), 
tungstenite::Message::Text("message_2".to_string()) ];

let send_stream: tokio_tungstenite::WebSocketStream
<tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::Message> 
= futures::stream::iter_ok(my_messages);

sink.send_all(stream).map_err(|e| ()).wait();
```

But it doesn't work, because futures::stream::iter_ok isn't the correct way to construct the stream I need, which is where I'm stuck and cannot see how to proceed from the documentation.

Edit: Originally I did not specify a type annotation for the send_stream and it gave me this error:

```
type annotations needed for `futures::stream::iter_ok::IterOk
<std::vec::IntoIter<tungstenite::protocol::message::Message>, E>`

cannot infer type for `E`
```

The current error is also to do with type annotations for the send stream.

Comment: An error message would really help, as would an MCVE. I found your problem, but the **actual** error/output rather than a human translation would've saved me 10 minutes.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld My apologies. Thank you for the input, I will be updating the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies squarely on this line:

```rust
let send_stream:tokio_tungstenite::WebSocketStream<tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::Message> 
    = futures::stream::iter_ok(my_messages);
```

The definition of [`futures::stream::iter_ok`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.2.1/futures/stream/fn.iter_ok.html) is as follows:

```
pub fn iter_ok<I, E>(i: I) -> IterOk<<I as IntoIterator>::IntoIter, E> 
where
    I: IntoIterator,
```

Notice that this new stream is an `IterOk`, not a `tungstenite::WebsocketStream`. By forcing the type (with your annotations), you are forcing the compiler to look for an implementation of `Into<WebsocketStream>` for `IterOk`, which there is none.

As a result, this fails.

This type hint was completely unnecessary as `send_all` is defined for `impl Sink<SinkItem = _, SinkError = _>`.

Without too much surprise, changing the line to:

```
let send_stream = futures::stream::iter_ok(my_messages)
  .map_err(|_:()| tungstenite::error::Error::Utf8)
```

should work flawlessly, as your sink expects `tungstenite::Message` and this new stream has that as an element (as it was built from a `Vec<tungstenite::Message>`). The `map_err` is there purely to coerce types and will **never be called in practice**.

Comment: Thank you for the input. That unfortunately doesn't work and I will explain. Omiting the type annotation is what I did originally, and it gives me this error:  type annotations needed for `futures::stream::iter_ok::IterOk<std::vec::IntoIter<tungstenite::protocol::message::Message>, E>`

cannot infer type for `E`. I am updating the question to include this information as it's not very readable down here. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @jamespearson Try with the `map_err()` type coercion. You will need to have `tungstenite` available, evidently. The aim of this is purely to get types to resolve.

Comment: doing that transfers the type annotation error to the map_err saying that the "_" underscore closure parameter of the map_err needs a type.

Comment: @jamespearson Surprised at that, but okay. Error type of `iter_ok()`, since it cannot fail, is `()`. Edited snippet, and [https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0fbbf780d04816e5f49c0fe719f33adf](the playground) seems to agree.

Comment: @sebastian Thanks that cracked it and I accepted your answer. For some reason doing send_all like that causes the websocket server I am speaking to send a close response ending the connection (perhaps due to send_all closing the sink). Do you happen to know a way around that?

Comment: @jamespearson `send_all` takes `self` and returns a new `Sink`. if you do not keep this return value somewhere, it is dropped and the connection is closed.

Comment: @jamespearson just to specify a bit more on the previous comment - when you do *anything* to a sink, on the outside, you consume it. Any call aimed at not closing it will return `self` in some form or other. It is up to you to choose to drop or not to drop it, and (since RAII), if you do cause it to drop, it'll close the channel.

Comment: @sebastian Thanks for that explanation. How do I prevent sink being dropped though?  My sink is here `let (mut sink, stream) = ws_stream.split(); ` and beneath that I have `sink.send_all(send_stream).map_err(|e| {println!("e = {:?}", e); ()}).and_then(|(passed_sink, _)|{
   // how do I keep passed_sink?
    Ok(())
} ).wait();`

Comment: I tried the simple thing of assigning `passed_sink` above to `mut sink` but due to ownership rules that's not allowed.

Comment: @jamespearson welcome to the fun world of futures. I'll be home in an hour or so (I was on and off planes the entire days) - let's continue this in chat a bit later if you like, I'll be happy to show you the pitfalls and how to avoid them!

Comment: Thanks so much! I really appreciate the help in getting me over the finish line. Something I've found which may help is for 0.1 futures `send_all` closes the `sink` connection afterwards, whereas in the new futures they have changed `send_all` so it doesn't (https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/futures-rs/issues/462 https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/futures-rs/pull/745). I haven't been able to take advantage of this though as I need 0.1 futures.

Comment: There's also a patch I've seen to use a custom send_all function (in the above links) but it doesn't give the results I was expecting.

Comment: futures 0.1 did have that problem. Why are you specifically stuck on 0.1? it may be worth isolating and either patching or replacing the dependency that causes you to not be able to use 0.2. Back then, most people got around this issue by having a stream closable on demand being fed to `send_all`, typically from a mpsc `channel` or their own implementation. mpsc channels have the interesting property that when all senders are dropped, the stream finishes - this makes them perfect for this.

Comment: Good news, I got the patched send_all function I referenced above working! It actually works like a charm, my first test of it was a case of good ol' user error. So that solves it! Phew. Thanks again for your original answer and patience! Have a nice day :)